Qual a vantagem da chamada dinâmica dentro da linguagem de programação C#?
Vou contextualizar a minha pergunta com alguns trechos de código. Basicamente estive lendo sobre métodos anônimos,expressões lambda e delegates em c#. O exemplo que eu vi traz o seguinte:
MyIntAndString contains = delegate(int i, string s){Console.WriteLine(s.Contains(i.ToString()));};

É um método anônimo que me retorna true ou false se encontrar um int dentro de uma string fornecida. Por exemplo, retorna false na linha abaixo:
contains(123,"four five six");

E me retorna true no caso abaixo:
contains(123,"four 123 five six");

Daí o exemplo mostra que é possível fazer uma chamada dinâmica usando um delegate, como as linhas abaixo mostram, passando os parâmetros para o método como um array de objetos.
Delegate d =  contains;
d.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {123,"four 123 five six"});

Essas últimas linhas representam a chamada dinâmica, mas não está claro pra mim qual a vantagem de fazer esse tipo de chamada. Quando usar e o que isso auxilia no código? Menor alocação de memória?

Dinamicidade, só isso. Eventualmente é necessário.

Em quais situações poderia ser necessário ? E a dinamicidade seria no tempo de execução do programa ?

Eu estive a investigar o código do Dotnet e encontrei apenas um cenário onde o DynamicInvoke é utilizado. Parece-me que este método deve ser utilizado quando o delegate não é conhecido em tempo de compilação, ou seja quando você não sabe o retorno e os parametros do delegate. Este método também deve ser evitado e substituido pelo método Invoke sempre que seja possível por motivos de performance.
De acordo com a resposta do SOEN do Marc Gravel

However! If you just know that it is Delegate, it has to resolve the
parameters etc manually - this might involve unboxing, etc - a lot of
reflection is going on. For example:
...

the array
validating the passed arguments are a "fit" for the actual MethodInfo
unboxing etc as necessary
reflection-invoke
then the caller needs to do something to process the return value

Basically, avoid
DynamicInvoke when-ever you can. Invoke is always preferable, unless
all you have is a Delegate and an object[].

Traduzindo:
Contudo! Se você apenas souber que é um delegate terá que resolver os parametros manualmente. Isto pode implicar unboxing e reflexão envovilda. Por exemplo...

o array
Validação se os argumentos correspondem ao MethodInfo
Unboxing caso haja necessidade
Invocação via reflexão
Processamento do resultado por parte do chamador

Basicaemte evite usar DynamicInvoke sempre que puder. Invoke é sempre preferível, a não ser que tudo o que tenha seja um Delegate e um object[]
